# Loading image from localStorage to canvas works only every second refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, local-storage, image

I have a little canvas where random rectangles are drawn every time you click on it. On every new rectangle added, the whole canvas is saved to *localStorage*.

When the webpage is refreshed the last saved image from localStorage is loaded.

**PROBLEM:**
I have to refresh twice to get the last image/capture. Rrefreshing once gives me only a blank canvas. Why is this?

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas onclick="draw(this, event);" id="drawarea" height="240" width="320" style="border:1px solid black;">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
"use strict;"

window.onload=function(){
    c=document.getElementById("drawarea");
    if (c) initCanvas(c);
};

function initCanvas(canvas){
    // Load last canvas
    loadLastCanvas(canvas);
}

function draw(canvas, event){

    // Draw at random place
    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect (250*Math.random()+1, 220*Math.random()+1, 40, 30);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // Save canvas
    saveCanvas(canvas);
}

function saveCanvas(c){
    localStorage['lastImgURI']=c.toDataURL("image/png");
}

function loadLastCanvas(c){
    if (!localStorage['lastImgURI']) return;
    img = new Image();
    img.src= localStorage['lastImgURI'];
    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `img.src = ""` is an asynchronous call. So you have to add a callback to the `onload` event. See [html5canvastutorials.com](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/) for more information.

```
function loadLastCanvas(c){
    if (!localStorage['lastImgURI']) return;
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
       ctx=c.getContext("2d");
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    };
    img.src= localStorage['lastImgURI'];
}
```